# Get a list of images from image gallery without using Android pictures selection

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, photo-gallery

I'm working on a new phonegap APP on Android.

I would like to know how to retrieve a list of pictures according to the date they were taken and display them to the user without using the camera roll.

Something like :

- get a list of pictures taken today
- display those pictures with a Yes/No selector
- send all the pictures selected by email

I've been testing the cordova-plugin-camera plugin and I've seen that it only allows me to select one picture at a time.

Any idea on how to do that ?

Thank you.

Comment: You access the images data via a content provider. Use a plugin which allows you to access content providers.

Comment: Thank you. I had a look at the content providers but it seems that the images can come from multiple sources (SD card, local files...) which makes it more difficult for users to choose (and more code). I'm experimenting with the cordova-imagePicker plugin.